# Symfony2 on shared hosting returning 404

Tags: php, apache, symfony, caching, shared-hosting

A web app which has been developed on a local apache (on Centos) works as intended and all routing works fine. However, when uploading the same identical project on a shared hosting, using the same path, and clearing the cache several times , the server is returning 404.

routing.yml:

```
app:
     resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
     type:     annotation

maya:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/MayaController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Furthermore, routing is specified on the controller method as:

```
/**
 * @Route("/maya/")
 */
public function initLoad()
{
    return $this->render(
        'base.html.twig');
}
```

Cache has been cleared by using the `php app/console cache:clear --env prod` command and `rm -fr app/cache/*`.

When accessing the web folder i.e www.mywebsite.com/my-site-folder/web/ a list of all the files inside the web folder are listed and when accessing www.mywebsite.com/my-site-folder/web/app.php the base template is being returned i.e as if www.mywebsite.com/my-site-folder/web/maya has been called.

Any suggestions on what the issue may be given it runs well on a local apache server on linux?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, sometimes when I clear the cache the error :Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in /home/mywebsite/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 71  This is rectified by running rm -fr for the cache folder. Could it be a PHP version mismatch? I am using symfony 2.8

Comment: Try this `@Route("/maya/")` to `@Route("/maya")`

Comment: Works when app.php is added in the url i.e: www.mywebsite.com/my-site-folder/web/app.php/maya works as intended. Still I find it strange why the app.php is required while locally on my apache it did not. Locally apache was running on prod mode. Thanks!

Comment: @William this is because .htaccess is either not uploaded on your server, .htaccess support is not enabled, or rewrite rules is not enabled. I suggest you contact your host and ask them if .htaccess support is enabled and if so, if rewrite rules are enabled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read your comments, I see accessing your site via /web/app.php works, I suspect .htaccess is not parsed by the server. Pleas ensure

- Symfony's .htaccess file is correctly uploaded in /web/ directory,
- your host has not enabled .htaccess support,
- or if .htaccess support is enabled, possible rewrite rules are disabled.

I suggest you check this with your host.

**NOTE:**
the `routing.yml` you provided, already includes your MayaController.php:

```
app:
     resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
     type:     annotation
```

you don't need to separately reference this:

```
maya:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/MayaController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689822/symfony-htaccess-to-hide-app-php-or-app-dev-php . Thanks for pointing to the right direction!

Comment: @William no problem! out of curiosity, `.htaccess` didn't exist in your symfony distribution?

Comment: nope. I used the symfony installer, creating a project version 2.8

Comment: If you check [symfony's source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/web/.htaccess) on github for `2.8` branch  you see `.htaccess` is already there. Did you upload files to your shared hosting server using FTP? Possibly your FTP client did not upload hidden files.

Comment: Quite possibly yes, although I did the upload from a CentOS dist, in which I do not recall that hidden files were not shown/omitted but a possibility nonetheless. Thanks a lot for your assistance it sure helped me!